How to avoid ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException on retry operation for long-running workers?
I have a long-running worker that performs network operations. If a network error happens during the operations, the worker is stopped with the Retry worker result. Android then automatically restarts the worker after a given delay if network conditions are met.
The worker is enqueued as follow:
val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>(
    repeatInterval = 1L,
    repeatIntervalTimeUnit = TimeUnit.HOURS,
)
    .setConstraints(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
    .addBackoffCriteria(30L)
    .build()

WorkManager.getInstance(context)
    .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
        MyWorker.workerUniqueName,
        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
        workRequest,
    )

And setForegroundAsync() is called before running the long-time operation inside the doWork() of the worker.
I also follow the guidelines described in the Android guide - Support for long-running workers. The foreground service type declared is dataSync.
Given the worker is started with 4G+Wifi, When the Wifi is disabled, Then the worker is stopped (with the above Retry worker result). In that case, every time the system tries to restart the worker (retry policy) while the app is in background, I have the following exception in an Android 14 device:
Moving WorkSpec (...) to the foreground
startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service com.myapp/androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService
android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service com.myapp/androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService
    at android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException$1.createFromParcel(ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.java:54)
    at android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException$1.createFromParcel(ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.java:50)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableInternal(Parcel.java:4870)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:4852)
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3052)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3041)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3024)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2966)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startService(IActivityManager.java:5984)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1931)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startForegroundService(ContextImpl.java:1906)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startForegroundService(ContextWrapper.java:830)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api26Impl.startForegroundService(ContextCompat.java:1189)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startForegroundService(ContextCompat.java:752)
    at androidx.work.impl.Processor.startForeground(Processor.java:206)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.WorkForegroundUpdater$1.run(WorkForegroundUpdater.java:100)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutorImpl$Task.run(SerialExecutorImpl.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    ...
Moving WorkSpec (...) to the foreground
Work [ id=..., tags={ ...MyWorker } ] failed because it threw an exception/error
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: android.app.BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=ACTION_NOTIFY cmp=com.myapp/androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{... TRNB bg:+2m17s737ms idle change:procadj procs:0 seq(401644,401374)} caps=------
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:515)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:474)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:316)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutorImpl$Task.run(SerialExecutorImpl.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    ...
Worker result FAILURE for Work [ id=..., tags={ ...MyWorker } ]
Unable to stop foreground service
android.app.BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND cmp=com.myapp/androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{... TRNB bg:+2m17s772ms idle change:procadj procs:0 seq(401644,401374)} caps=------
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1945)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1900)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:825)
    at androidx.work.impl.Processor.stopForegroundService(Processor.java:403)
    at androidx.work.impl.Processor.cleanUpWorkerUnsafe(Processor.java:425)
    at androidx.work.impl.Processor.onExecuted(Processor.java:345)
    at androidx.work.impl.Processor.lambda$startWork$1$androidx-work-impl-Processor(Processor.java:179)
    at androidx.work.impl.Processor$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    ...


In other cases I tested where the worker is stopped and relaunched while app was in background, I didn't get the above exception.
Do you have any idea why I have this exception, in that case and only in that case? Have you faced similar issues?

And you put a permission FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC into a manifest file?

Yes I did declare the FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC permission. I think the exception would have been different otherwise.
